# Showing the hidden Winform

Tags: c#, windows, message

I have two independent application. First application is called **MSGAPP** and other is called **SCUForm**.

I am controlling the the **SCUForm** through **MSGAPP** application by sending the Windows Messages. I can minimize, maximize the **SCUForm** application by sending the Windows Messages through MSGAPP. And I can also Hide the **SCUForm**. But when I hide the application, I am not able to show the form back.

what I should do to show it back.

I tried `this.Show()` but no use.

Am I missing some basics here?

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

-Harsha

Comment: `this.Show()` is not a Windows message. You can't use it with the `SendMessage` function. What does your code look like?

Comment: Please show us your code. We can solve problems, but only if we have something to work with!!

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well (I did it some year ago), you should try to use WM_SYSCOMMAND with SC_RESTORE.
Watch [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
You could find [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/105571) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/windowhider.aspx) useful, perhaps.